# how to pass a function to a tuple from a thread

Tags: python, tuples

My questions are interlaced within my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import logging, logging.handlers
import hpclib
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime
from features import *
import sys


if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print "Please provide the correct inputs"
        print "Usage: rest_test.py <controllerip> <counter>"
    sys.exit()


controller = sys.argv[1]
counter = int(sys.argv[2])



class FuncThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self._target = target
        self._args = args
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self._target(*self._args)

def datapath_thread(ipaddress, testlogfile,count):
    #initialize logging system
    testlogger = logging.getLogger("testlogger")
    testlogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file = open(testlogfile,'w')
    file.close()
    # This handler writes everything to a file.
    h1 = logging.FileHandler(testlogfile)
    f = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s")
    h1.setFormatter(f)
    h1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    testlogger.addHandler(h1)
    mylib = hpclib.hpclib(ipaddress)
    success_count = 0
    failure_count = 0
    for i in range(count):
        t1=datetime.now()
        try:
            (code, val) = datapaths.listDatapaths(mylib)
```

I want to pass this function `datapaths.listDatapaths(mylib)` as a argument from a thread below, something like `(code,val)=functionname`

```
            if code == 200:
                success_count +=1
            else:
                testlogger.debug("Return Code other than 200 received with code = %d, value = %s"%(code,val))
                failure_count +=1
        except:
            failure_count += 1
            testlogger.debug ("Unexpected error: %s"%sys.exc_info()[0])
            continue

        t2=datetime.now()
        diff=t2-t1
        testlogger.debug('RETURN code: %d. Time taken in sec = %s,Iteration = %d, Success = %d, Failure = %d'%(code,diff.seconds,i+1,success_count,failure_count))
        time.sleep(1)

    testlogger.removeHandler(h1)

# Passing ipadress of controller and log file name
t1 = FuncThread(datapath_thread, controller, "datapaths.log",counter)
```

Here I would like to pass function name as one of the argument,something like `t1 = FuncThread(datapath_thread, controller, datapaths.listDatapaths(mylib),"datapaths.log",counter)`

```
t1.start()
t1.join()
```

I have many functions to call like this,so want a easy way to call all the functions from one single function using many threads

Comment: I know that function scope makes it ok, but using `t1` to refer to a thread and a datetime in the same file is asking for trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `FuncThread` is not very useful - `FuncThread(func, *args)` can be spelt `Thread(target=lambda: func(*args))` or `Thread(target=func, args=args)`.

You're pretty close - instead of passing in the *result* of calling the function, pass in the function itself

```
def datapath_thread(ipaddress, test_func, testlogfile, count):
    # ...
    for i in range(count):
        # ...
        try:
            (code, val) = test_func(mylib)
        #...
```

```
thread = Thread(target=datapath_thread, args=(
    controller,
    datapaths.listDatapaths,
    "datapaths.log",
    counter
))
```

Comment: Thanks Eric for the help..
I met with a new problem now.
I created a new thread and called a different function some thing like
t2 = FuncThread(datapaths_thread, controller,links.listAllLinks,"listalllinks.log",counter)
t2.start()

But i see the same data is captured in both the logs instead of t1 thread capturing t1's function log alone and vice versa.

Comment: That's because you're passing the same argument to `logging.getLogger` each time, which means you get the same logger. - from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects) - _"Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object."_